# How to check current tag element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've a GridView with three rows like this

```
<tr>
   <th>SlNo</th>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>2</td>
</tr>
```

I've the following code to traverse through the rows

```
var GridViewRow=GridView.getElementsByTagName('tr')
```

Here the row length is 3.

I travese through the `GridViewRow` using for loop .Here how will i get the tag name of the current element ie (`th or td`).

If the tagname is "`TH`" it should return and if it is "`TD`" it should take the value of TD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this

```
var table = document.getElementById("mytab1"); 
for (var i = 0, cell; cell = table.cells[i]; i++) {      
//iterate through cells      
//cells would be accessed using the "cell" variable assigned in the for loop 
}
```

you can also try out

```
var tbl = document.getElementById('yourTableId'); 
var rows = tbl.getElementsByTagName('tr'); 
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) 
{     
    if(rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td').length > 0)
    {
      //code to execute
    }
    else
    {
      continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var GridViewRow = GridView.getElementsByTagName('tr');
$(GridViewRow).each(function() {
   var $this = $(this), td = $this.find('td');
   if (td.length === 1) {
      console.log(td.text());
   }
});
```

this works for `<tr>` in which you have exactly one `<td>` if you use jquery, otherwise in plain javascript try this:

```
var GridViewRow = GridView.getElementsByTagName('tr'),
    len = GridViewRow.length,
    td;

    while (--len) {
       td = GridViewRow[len].getElementsByTagName('td');
       if (td.length === 1) {
           console.log(td[0].innerHTML);
       }
    }   
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check the tag name with jQuery :

```
$(this).attr("tag");
```

Later edit:

For raw javascript, use [tagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.tagName):

```
element.tagName
```

Comment: I'm using javascript not jquery

Comment: `.attr("tag")` makes no sense. In jQuery you'd use `.is('th')` or `.prop('tagName') == 'TH'`. Besides, w3s is a really bad resource - see http://w3fools.com